# Is there a formula to automate a named range?

Tags: join, google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**Product** = Column A | **Quantity** = Column B |

```
Oranges | 2    
Apples  | 4
```

**Desired Output**

- Oranges
- Oranges
- Apples
- Apples
- Apples
- Apples

**Formula**

```
=if(row()<=$B$2, indirect("A" &"2", True), "")
```

My formula spits out Oranges twice, as expected but I seem to can't figure out how to build the formula so that apples spits out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN( ,REPT("♦"&A1:A2, B1:B2)), "♦")))
```

[image]

Comment: Question: this doesn't translate into excel smoothly, any thoughts how to streamline this?

Comment: not rly sure and I have no way to test it so I would say no

Comment: ok, no problem. This means more time to play around with this. The diamond was utilized as delimiter correct?

Comment: yes, thats correct. you can change it to any symbol of your choosing ♣♠♥♂♀♫♪...

Comment: Lets say row A3 I added, {Bananas, cherries}. Is there a way to split that out as well, can I simply put a transpose code around your formula?

Comment: I have a "baby" formula, which reads, =transpose(split(A3,",",1,1) but I am doubting the automation

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: what is your email add?